# preparing training data that I can use tf.argmax for testing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm using CIFAR for Tensorflow training, but I'm changing MNIST code into what I need now, but I can't figure out a way to let `tf.argmax` do the job by its original design. Now need to turn array like,

```
[2, 7, 1, 5, 3]
```

into

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

how can I do it? I'm using CIFAR 100 database, here you can [get my code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jgye2pj4iojmsz/tf_cifar.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Post the code here. Don't just post a problem and expect someone to solve it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you need is `one-hot encoding`. To get the one-hot encoding specify the indices as a python list and pass it to [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#one_hot) along with the needed `depth` :

```
# a numpy array could also work
In [85]: idx = [2, 7, 1, 5, 3]

In [86]: one_hot_vec = tf.one_hot(idx, depth=8, dtype=tf.int32)

In [87]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [91]: one_hot_vec = tf.one_hot(idx, depth=8, dtype=tf.int32)

In [92]: one_hot_vec.eval()
Out[92]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: @Divakar I'm puzzled as well. Let's see what the OP has to say about it.